# Python modifying `__lt__` outside of class definition

Tags: python

I have a file with defines a `class X`, and inside that class there is a definition for `def __lt__(self, other):`.

In another file, I have a heapq of `X`'s. However, this pq needs to compare `X`'s differently than what is defined in `__lt__`.

Is there a way for me to overide the `__lt__` for `X`'s in this file? Or is there a better way for me to use a custom comparator for the heapq?

Comment: You could make a new class that inherits from `X`, and overwrites the `__lt__` while keeping everything else the same.

Comment: You can monkey-patch the class, `X.__lt__ = whatever`, then you can undo that when you are done. A hackey solution, though

Comment: Which version of Python?

Comment: I am using 3.6.5. I was doing the `X.__lt__ = whatever` solution before, however this seems like an awkward workaround